# Why cant I add a custom post type to a custom taxonomy?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, wp-insert-post

I am trying to assign a custom taxonomy to a custom post type with `wp_insert_post` function.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type'     => 'custom_post_type',
  'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( $title ),
  'post_content'  => 'some content',
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => $author_id,
  'post_category' => array($category_id), //$category_id = 33;
);
$new_cpt_id = wp_insert_post( $args );
```

A quick fix for now is:

```
wp_set_object_terms( $new_cpt_id, $category_id, 'custom_tax_category' );
```

However, I want to do it with `wp_insert_post` function.

**NOTE**
I am using the following inside the `$args` for `register_post_type( 'custom_post_type', $args );`

```
'taxonomies' => array( 'custom_tax_category','custom_tax_tag' ),
```

So, what am I missing?

Comment: what is the context of when the code runs? have you seen the note in codex for `wp_insert_post`: *If the current user doesn't have the capability to work a taxonomy, then you must use wp_set_object_terms() instead*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `post_category` you are using is for core categories taxonomy. For custom taxonomies you have to use `tax_input`. For example, the next code set terms for `custom_tax_category` and `custom_ta_tag` taxonomies.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'custom_post_type',
    'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( $title ),
    'post_content'  => 'some content',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_author'   => $author_id,
    'tax_input'     => array(
                           'custom_tax_category' => array( $category_id ),
                           'custom_tax_tag'      => array( $tag_id )
     ),
);
$new_cpt_id = wp_insert_post( $args );
```

Comment: Great, that worked! Where in the codex is that? I could not find it.

Comment: The [wp_insert_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) codex explain that already. Sorry, I've visited the codex and the documentation about `tax_input` is very poor; I'm going to suggest a edit.